# Check if product got upsell product

Tags: product, up-sells, product-page

I want to display a `li` on `product-page`, *if the product got upsell products*.

What is the condition that I need to check for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<?php if (count($_product->getUpSellProductIds()) > 0) : ?>

    <!-- your list should come inside this condition-->
    <ul>
        <li>item-1</list>
        <li>item-2</list>
        <li>item-3</list>
    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If you have a valid product object on `$_product`, then `getUpSellProductIds()` will provides you an array of upsell product ids related to the product which holds by `$_product`. So what we are doing here is checking whether the array count is greater than zero. If it is yes, then shows the list.

Hope you get the concept.

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: I wish to get only the in stock upsell product collection, then how do i add filter while getting a collection itself

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. In your `view.phtml` file write this code where your want to display "**li**" or any HTML code:

[image]

Also you can use `$upsell_products` in a `foreach()` loop to get each product and attributes.